# Facebook authentication on Azure Mobile Services do not complete

Tags: facebook, azure-mobile-services

I have created an Azure Mobile Services using .NET backend.

I am trying to authenticate on Azure Mobile Services with Facebook using the azure mobile services client.

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.1.3.min.js.

```
function logIn() {
    client.login("facebook").then(refreshAuthDisplay, function(error){
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

Facebook Login popup is appearing and I was able to enter the Facebook credential/password.

The latest request is being executed successfully, I am logged into facebook.

https://{azure_mobile_url}/login/done?completion_type=postMessage&completion_origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A6568

However the Facebook login popup is not being closed therefore the javascript promises "complete" callback is not executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the .NET backend does not support authentication using the Javascript client. It is being worked on, and will be supported before the .NET runtime leaves preview status.

Comment: Interesting information. I've been struggling with the same problem. Where did you find this information?

Comment: Is this still the case today? I'm having the same issue with Google authentication when using Ripple. On an Android emulator it seems to work fine.